# Is there a way to create per-face/per-vertex normals?

Tags: vertices, normals, faces

Is there a way in Blender to create per-face/per-vertex normals?

All I can find for now, is per-vertex normal. If, with a bmesh, I'm going into a face and then the loop. But for each item in the loop, I can't find a normal. There's a "vert" property, which has a normal. But that vertex is shared with adjacent faces. So, if I modify that normal, it changes the normal of this vertex on the other faces it's on.

Is there a way to achieve this? Or maybe it's like Max and it has a sort of layer of it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible since 2.74 release (see the [release notes](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.74/Modeling#Custom_Normals)). Upcoming 2.75 release will include some rather important fixes for them too.

You can only manipulate them in 'Object' mode though (i.e. not in BMesh), and there are several other limitations that may be addressed in future - in a few words, they are mostly procedural currently (through modifiers), and you should only use them on final topology, any topology change (adding/removing verts/edges/faces, or even applying negative scaling) will more or less break them.

Comment: I installed the one from Ubuntu repo with 2.69. I'll check to update soon and use that approach. Thanks for the fast answer.