# Bmesh: how can I import custom vertex normals

Tags: python, import, bmesh

I have a question concerning BMesh and custom vertex normals editing. At the moment I am writing a little blender importer for a custom data format and I am stuck with importing/manipulating custom vertex normals. I am using the bmesh module because I want to use it's functionalities before transforming the bmesh into a real mesh.

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to set the normals with bmesh? Do I need to import them with the Mesh module?

Thanks a lot in advance for any tipp!

Comment: probably related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32292/is-there-a-way-to-create-per-face-per-vertex-normals

Comment: might also have a look at [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49506/2271)

Comment: thanks. I will most definately have to do it with the mesh module instead of bmesh. Bmesh just offers so much more functionality to work with...

Answer (score 2):

I believe since Blender 2.74, this was made possible for the bpy `Mesh` type. You can use the mesh [`normals_split_custom_set`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bpy.types.Mesh.html?highlight=normals_split_custom_set#bpy.types.Mesh.normals_split_custom_set) method to do this.

In this example, I only have per-vertex normals so I create a new list with one normal corresponding to each loop.

```
normals2 = []
for l in mesh.loops:
    normals2.append(normals[l.vertex_index])
mesh.normals_split_custom_set(normals2)
mesh.use_auto_smooth = True
```

Note that auto smooth needs to be enabled for this to work.

In my case, I could have used the `normals_split_custom_set_from_vertices` method, and passed in normals directly.

Comment: Yes, thats what I am doing now. Thanks. I WANT to use the Bmesh module though because of it's functionalities. Vertex normals are not supported (yet) though - it turns out - and the information gets lost if you transform the mesh to bmesh.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably as simple as

```
mesh = obj.data
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(mesh)

bm.verts[i].normal = [ x,y,z]

bm.to_mesh(mesh)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, sadly it's not that easy since I need to set the normals per face loop (one vertex can habe multiple normals, which is the whole purpose of split normals)

Comment: The few things I have read imply that blender does not fully support per-face vertex normals yet.  I don't know if it is on the roadmap.

Comment: And even setting per-vertex normals seems to be ineffective.  You can even do `obj.data.vertices[0].normal = [1,0,0]` and the value will be reset to default if you go in and out of edit mode.