# Flat shaded mesh - missing separate colours/normals for connected vertices?

Tags: python, vertex-colors

I recently got started with python scripting, so I am still very new to this!

I am trying to set the vertex color of vertices looking'up' to white, otherwise set it to black.

I use a dot product to determine whether a vertex is pointing upwards or not (vertex.normal.dot(Vector((0,0,1))) > 0.9)

I run my script on the default cube, and it doesn't work correctly. I noticed that even though I have flat shading enabled, the vertices are all connected and 'share' a normal and color. For this reason, I can't make the 4 vertices that define the top of the cube white and the vertices that are a part of the sides of the cube black. They share the information. Here is what I get when I run my script:

[image]

If I separate the top faces and run the script again, the colouring is correct as expected. But whats strange is that if I remove duplicates to reattach the vertices back together again, the colour information is retained! This is what I expected it to do in the first place. Here is a screenshot. In the left image, the faces are still separated - you can see that the upwards facing faces have their own normals pointing straight up, as they are not attached to the rest of the mesh. In the right image, I have run the 'remove duplicates' command to merge everything back together. The normals on the corners now look like they are merged again, but the colour information is retained.

[image]

I was wondering how I can define this extra colour information via script, without having to detach the faces first (which defeats the purpose of the script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ll want to use “split normals”.

1. Set your faces to 'smooth' shading, and enable `use_auto_smooth` mesh option).
2. Compute the normals (`mesh.calc_normals_split()`).
3. Access them from loops (`mesh.loops[0].normal`).
4. Don’t forget to free them once you do not need them anymore (`mesh.free_normals_split()`).