# There is a way to add custom split normal use Python API?

Tags: python, scripting, bmesh

I can't find a way to achieve custom split normal effect.
I want to use python (mesh normal/hard edge or soft edge) data collected from Maya then write to Blender mesh.

How to do it using the following Python API and how?

`bpy.data.meshes[objName].normals_split_custom_set_from_vertices`

`bmesh module`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Custom Split Normals**

Elaborating on [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/52002/15543) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49500/flat-shaded-mesh-missing-separate-colours-normals-for-connected-vertices)

Test script. Run in object mode.  Switch to edit mode to see results.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
me = ob.data
# visualize in edit mode    
me.show_normal_vertex = me.show_normal_loop = True
me.use_auto_smooth = True
# normal custom verts on each axis
me.normals_split_custom_set([(0, 0, 0) for l in me.loops])
```

[image]
*end up with custom split normals in each of the corner directions. Blue are the vert normals*

```
# all custom split normals pointing up.
normals = [(0, 0, 1) for v in me.vertices]
# make csn's all face up.  
me.normals_split_custom_set_from_vertices(normals)
```

[image]
*all custom split normals facing up `(0, 0, 1)`*

I am not aware if custom split normals can be accessed from `bmesh`.

Comment: really appreciate,  I got your idea, and to get a hard/soft edge effect, except setting custom normal split, what else I need? setting sharp edge?

Comment: I try it, and I think it is no need to mark sharp edge,  I get same hard/soft edge effect like same mesh in Maya.what's your idea?

Comment: @XuqiangZhang forgot to mention needs to be run in object mode.