# How to set custom vertex normals for certain vertices using python?

Tags: python, scripting, normals, geometry

I am struggling to set custom vertex normal vector just for certain/selected vertices in an object with python. I searched through the documentation and forums but nothing really helps so far.

[This question/answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104650/there-is-a-way-to-add-custom-split-normal-use-python-api) answers only to how to set split normal to a whole object. However, I want to set custom normals to just some parts of the object. See the picture below:

[image: Changing jut one or several normals]

**Q:** How can I add custom normals just to certain vertices in and object?

*Would be helpful if someone could share something simple as possible.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There is a way to add custom split normal use Python API?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104650/there-is-a-way-to-add-custom-split-normal-use-python-api)

Comment: Nope it doesn't...I still don't know how to set custom split normal only for certain vertex normals in an object

Comment: Edit your question, add what's wrong with the linked answer, what you've tried or what you'd like to get to your question in order to re-open it @skywalger

Comment: done, It shoud be now more understandable what I want to achieve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example of assigning custom normals based on vertex selection. It's just a slight modification of the code given in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/104664/31447) and assigns a custom *vector* to vertices in selection.

[image]

Run the script in *Object Mode* and enable `show_split_normal` property in *Edit Mode*:

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
me = ob.data

me.use_auto_smooth = True

# Normal custom verts on each axis
me.normals_split_custom_set([(0, 0, 0) for l in me.loops])

# Set normal for selected vertices
normals = []
for v in me.vertices:
    if v.select:
    # if v.index in (0, 1, 4): # Alternatively you can ask for certain indices
        normals.append((0, 0, -0.5))
    else:
        normals.append(v.normal)

# make csn's all face up.  
me.normals_split_custom_set_from_vertices(normals)

#me.free_normals_split()
```

Note: As of 2.8x `show_split_normal` property is part of the *Overlays* menu:

[image]

Comment: thank you thank you thank you :), that is exactly what i needed and didn't know how to. I just replace the condition "if v.select" by "if v == me.vertices[n]" and that is it

Comment: Better ask for the index of the vertex: `if v.index == 1:` @skywalger For the sake of completeness, I added how to ask for multiple indices to the answer.

Comment: @brockmann How to enable the option `show_split_normal` you mentioned in your answer? I was unable to find any information about that option.

Comment: I think for consistency it's now part of the *overlays* menu as of 2.8x @vvoovv: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6EYh.png

Comment: I see... It's the middle icon in the _Normals_ section of the _Overlays_ menu. I overlooked it somehow.